# how to use CSS nth child?

Tags: html, css

i have this unordered list

```
<ul>
     <li> test1</li>
     <li>test2 </li>
     <li class="current">test3</li>
     <li>test4</li>
</ul>
```

what i want to do is to select the `.current` child and access the `test2` from it. That means to select `.current` and go back one step back to `test2`

Same for `test1` go back two steps to get `test1` and associate different CSS to it.

Is it feasible ?

Comment: Fiddle your code please. I don't understand your issue.

Comment: i want to select the "li" just before the one which has a class "current"

Comment: You mean, you want to pass the class to the previous element?

Comment: i need to select the "li" that is just before the .current class

Comment: Does the markup has only 4 `li` tags or more or you don't know?

Comment: Are you OK with *all* previous items? Because you can sort-of do that: http://jsbin.com/oNuqUS/1/edit?html,css,output

Answer (score 5):

There is no previous sibling selector or parent selector, so no, it is not feasible with pure CSS.

If you used some javascript it would be quite easy, something like

```
document.getElementsByClassName('current')[0].previousSibling.style = /* Whatever you want here */;
```

Assuming that there is only one `current` class at a time

Comment: i cannot cant add javascript, i need to find any solution using css only

Comment: I'm afraid there is not one currently

Comment: There is no way to do it with CSS only

Comment: There is no way to do add, remove or pass classes within pure CSS, you can do it through Javascript, for example.

Comment: @Roh-Land Currently, there is no way, but checkout [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15503444/603003).

Answer (score 0):

In future browsers CSS Level 4 Selectors will enable you to solve this problem more easily using something like the following (WIP) :

```
!li + .current {}
```

See: http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors4/#subject